# How to find the device in a RAID1 under Linux?

Tags: raid

besides:

```
head -2 /dev/dm-16 | strings | grep ^id
```

how can I find that which device belongs to a given MD RAID1 array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since RAID1 means there are two identical disks, so checksums need to match

```
[root@SERVER ~]# head -100 /dev/sdb3|cksum
2207220453 6836
[root@SERVER ~]# head -100 /dev/sda3|cksum
2207220453 6836
[root@SERVER ~]#
```

Comment: hope it's a really good answer for every situation... metadata/etc could differ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Comment: doesn't shows which was the pair of the device that is in the RAID1 md.

Comment: md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
  =>  
sdb2, sda2 ? isn't that what you're referring to by "pair"?

Comment: it only shows 1 sdXX device :) I'm searching for it's pair

Comment: sdb2, sda2, are two devices. no?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
mdadm -D /dev/mdX
```

replacing `X` by your actual RAID-1 device number.

Comment: doesn't shows which was the pair of the device that is in the RAID1 md.

Comment: @gaskopeter It's been a while since I managed a RAID array. Can you please tell me what the output of `mdadm -D /dev/mdX` show on your box? and what you expected it to show?

Answer (score 0):

blkid(8) should be informative.